How to set bookmark with count limitation
I need to set the bookmark with character count limitations. For contents with more than 100 characters, only the first 100 characters should be shown, followed by an ellipsis (...). For contents with less than 100 characters, the full content should be displayed in the bookmark. (Compiling the file using lualatex-dev.exe)
My MWE is below
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\mytitle[1]{%
    \bgroup\pdfbookmark[0]{#1}{\@currentHref}\egroup%%% I need to set the bookmark count 100 followed by ellips
    \par\addvspace{12pt}%
    {\large\bfseries\selectfont\noindent\ignorespaces#1\par}\addvspace{12pt}%
    }
\makeatother

\mytitle{Title with more than 100 character Directed cycle $k$-connectivity$\textit{u}$ of complete digraphs and~complete regular bipartite $\alpha$ digraphs Please confirm that given names and surnames have been identified correctly. Please confirm that given names and surnames have been identified correctly.}

Friendships increase mental wellbeing and resilient functioning in young people with childhood adversity (CA). However, the mechanisms of this relationship are unknown. We examined the relationship between perceived friendship quality at age 14 after the experience of CA and reduced affective and neural responses to social exclusion at age 24. Resilient functioning was quantified as psychosocial functioning relative to the degree of CA severity in 310 participants at age 24.

\mytitle{Title with less than 100 character Directed cycle}

\end{document}

